# Suppose the joint density is given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=Ce^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y<\infty$ and 0 otherwise.

Tags: statistics

> Suppose the joint density is given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=Ce^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y<\infty$ and 0 otherwise.
>
> Determine C so that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a density and compute the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$.

I'm having problems finding C. I think $\int_0^\infty\int_0^y Ce^{-(x+y)}dxdy=1$. If it is a density function.

So solving that integral $\int_0^\infty-ce^{-2y}dy+\int_0^\infty ce^{-y}dy$

then $\frac{1}{2}ce^{-2y}\vert^\infty_0 - (ce^{-y}\vert^\infty_0)=\frac{-1}{2}c+c=1$

thus $c=2$

But when I compute the marginal density $F_X(x)=\int_0^y 2e^{-(x+y)}dy$

I get $F_X(x)=-2e^{-(x+y)}+2e^{-x}$

So I'm definitely doing something wrong. I think the bounds I'm using $0<x<y$ in the integral is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of $c$ is correct. But $f_X$ cannot depend on $y$ so your computation of $f_X$ is not correct.

$f_X(x)=2\int_x^{\infty} e^{-x-y} dy=2e^{-x} \int_x^{\infty} e^{-y} dy=2e^{-2x}$ for $0 <x<\infty$.

Comment: I guess I'm confused how to compute marginal density. What determines the boundary of the integral?

Comment: @AColoredReptile Fix $x$ and just look at the given conatraint $0<x<y<\infty$. This puts the restriction $y >x$ on $y$ which is the variable of integration for finding $f_X(x)$.

Comment: So you want $2e^{-x}\int_x^\infty e^{-y}dy$? Which should give you $-2e^{-2x}$

Comment: @AColoredReptile The integral of a positive function cannot be negative. So please check your calculation of $\int_x^{\infty} e^{-y}dy$. [I have corrected some typos in my answer].